# Scala: verify class parameter is not instanceOf a trait at compile time

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros, scala-reflect

At compile time I want to verify that a class parameter is NOT an instance of a particular trait T. I know how to do it at runtime using `require` or a `case match` but wondering how this might be done at compile to prevent users from providing certain type of object mixins.

I've looked into scala macros/reflection but not able to wrap my head around that completely.

```
trait A
trait B
trait T
abstract class C extends A with B

case class P(c: C){
  require(!c.isInstanceOf[T]) // how to do this at compile time ?
}

// usage as below
object c1 extends C
object c2 extends C
object c3 extends C
object c4 extends C with T

val l = List(c1, c2, c3, c4).map(k => P(k)) // should fail at compile time
```

Comment: Please see update with a magnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with `List`. All elements in `List(c1, c2, c3, c4)` will be of the same type i.e. `C` and information that one of them has type `C with T` will be lost.

`new C {}`, `new C with T {}` are runtime values of `c1, c2, c3, c4`, compiler doesn't have access to them while compiling `List(c1, c2, c3, c4)`.

You can do this with `HList`. Using `shapeless.<:!<`, `shapeless.ops.hlist.LiftAll` and kind-projector

```
def noElementIsSubtypeOfT[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit liftAll: LiftAll[* <:!< T, L]) = null

noElementIsSubtypeOfT(c1 :: c2 :: c3 :: HNil) // compiles
// noElementIsSubtypeOfT(c1 :: c2 :: c3 :: c4 :: HNil) // doesn't compile
```

Or

```
def noElementIsSubtypeOfT[L <: HList : LiftAll[* <:!< T, *]](l: L) = null
```

For class parameter you can do

```
case class P[U <: C](c: U)(implicit ev: U <:!< T)

P(c1) // compiles
P(c2) // compiles
P(c3) // compiles
// P(c4) // doesn't compile
```

or

```
case class P[U <: C : * <:!< T](c: U)
```

---

Actually, there is a way to fix the code with List. You can make class `P` implicit (so you define an implicit conversion) and specify the type of list `List[P[_]](...)` (so called magnet pattern [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643225/overloading-methods-based-on-generics) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313268/type-erasure-problem-in-method-overloading) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011072/how-to-make-a-typeclass-works-with-an-heterogenous-list-in-scala) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318180/generic-function-where-the-return-type-depends-on-the-input-type-in-scala) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651201/problem-with-bringing-into-scope-scala-implicit-conversions) [6](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73846768/scala-generic-method-no-classtag-available-for-t-when-using-collection), `P` is a magnet)

```
implicit class P[U <: C](c: U)(implicit ev: U <:!< T)

List[P[_]](c1, c2, c3) // compiles

List[P[_]](c1, c2, c3, c4) // doesn't compile, type mismatch: found: c4.type, required: P[_]
```

Comment: Thanks, it does not seem to be working with singleton objects extending an abstract class. The compilation gets through without any failures. 

Sorry I should have described my question better initially. I believe this might not be working for singletons because of lazy evaluation of singleton objects. Any workarounds for that ?

Comment: @bawejakunal How can lazy evaluation be relevant to compile time? Workarounds for what? Describe better what you try and what you get (compile errors etc.)

Comment: @bawejakunal I guess I already explained about `List` and `HList` in my answer. This can't work with `List`. Do you have further questions?

Comment: Thanks this works though I am wondering if this can work without using the kind-projector. For a project that I am working on adding that plugin may not be feasible in the short term.

Comment: @bawejakunal Yes, surely this can be written without kind-projector with type lambda: `def noElementIsSubtypeOfT[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit liftAll: LiftAll[({ type λ[X] = X <:!< T })#λ, L]) = null`.