# Overloading methods based on generics

Tags: scala, generics, overloading

I'd like to overload a method based on generics - so something like this:

```
case class Indexed2dArr[Dim0Type, Dim1Type] (
  indices: (List[Dim0Type], List[Dim1Type]),
  array: List[List[Float]],
) {
  def getSliceAtIndexLocation(i: Dim0Type): (List[Dim1Type], List[Float]) = ???
  def getSliceAtIndexLocation(i: Dim1Type): (List[Dim0Type], List[Float]) = ???
}
```

So if `getSliceAtIndexLocation` is called with a parameter of `Dim0Type`, it returns a single-dimensioned slice of the orginal array, with an index of `Dim1Type`. And vice-versa for calling with `Dim1Type`.

This raises a `double definition` compiler error - that the two methods have the same type after type erasure, this type being `(i: Object): Tuple2`. Is there a valid way to wrangle this or is it straight-up impossible?

Comment: You can use the `DummyImplicit` which basically exists for this. Or you can use **typelcasses**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - thank you - If you'd like to put the DummyImplicit method as an answer then I'll accept it. Would you mind explaining how typeclasses would help here?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - sorry, I understand what you mean by the typeclass-based approach now. But would this not require me to specify a typeclass for every possible concrete type for Dim0Type and Dim1Type?

Comment: @Chrisper No, just for `Dim0Type` and `Dim1Type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either `DummyImplicit`

```
case class Indexed2dArr[Dim0Type, Dim1Type] (
  indices: (List[Dim0Type], List[Dim1Type]),
  array: List[List[Float]],
) {
  def getSliceAtIndexLocation(i: Dim0Type): (List[Dim1Type], List[Float]) = ???
  def getSliceAtIndexLocation(i: Dim1Type)(implicit 
    di: DummyImplicit): (List[Dim0Type], List[Float]) = ???
}
```

or [type class](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/#type-classes-in-scala) pattern

```
case class Indexed2dArr[Dim0Type, Dim1Type] (
  indices: (List[Dim0Type], List[Dim1Type]),
  array: List[List[Float]],
) {
  def getSliceAtIndexLocation[A](i: A)(implicit tc: TC[A]): tc.Out = tc(i)

  trait TC[A] {
    type B
    type Out = TC.MkOut[B]
    def apply(i: A): Out
  }
  object TC {
    type MkOut[B] = (List[B], List[Float])

    type Aux[A, B0] = TC[A] { type B = B0 }
    def instance[A, B0](f: A => MkOut[B0]): Aux[A, B0] = new TC[A] {
      override type B = B0
      override def apply(i: A): Out = f(i)
    }
  
    implicit val dim0Type: Aux[Dim0Type, Dim1Type] = instance(i => ???)
    implicit val dim1Type: Aux[Dim1Type, Dim0Type] = instance(i => ???)
  }
}
```

or [magnet](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern) pattern

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

case class Indexed2dArr[Dim0Type, Dim1Type] (
  indices: (List[Dim0Type], List[Dim1Type]),
  array: List[List[Float]],
) {
  def getSliceAtIndexLocation(m: Magnet): m.Out = m()

  trait Magnet {
    type B
    type Out = Magnet.MkOut[B]
    def apply(): Out
  }
  object Magnet {
    type MkOut[B] = (List[B], List[Float])

    type Aux[B0] = Magnet { type B = B0 }
    def instance[B0](x: MkOut[B0]): Aux[B0] = new Magnet {
      override type B = B0
      override def apply(): Out = x
    }

    implicit def dim0Type(i: Dim0Type): Aux[Dim1Type] = instance(???)
    implicit def dim1Type(i: Dim1Type): Aux[Dim0Type] = instance(???)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you - it is going to take a while before I fully get my head around this but it works.

Comment: just for my own interest here, but presumably this cannot be done with an unknown number of generic arguments, ie varadic generics?

Comment: @Chrisper In Scala there are no variadic generics, but there is [`HList`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists): `case class SomeClass[L <: HList]()` `SomeClass[A :: B :: C :: HNil]()`. Type class can be defined correspondingly.

Comment: thanks - I've just started using that library and it looks very interesting. For the time being I am struggling to get all this stuff working with non-variadic generic parameters so I think I'll keep it simple for the time being, but it's nice to know there are other options out there when the time comes.