# Type erasure problem in method overloading

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, type-erasure

I have two overloaded method having following signatures -

```
def fun(x: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[Int]] = ???
def fun(x: Seq[(String, String)]): Future[Seq[Int]] = ???
```

Due to type erasure, these methods can't be overloaded and hence showing compilation error. I tried using typetags as a workaround  -

```
def fun[t: TypeTag](values: Seq[T]): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
    typeOf[T] match {
        case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => ???
        case t if t =:= typeOf[(String, String)] => ???
        case _ => ???    // Should not come here
     }
}
```

There are two problems with this approach that I am facing -

1. How can I use the values in the Seq ?
2. How can I avoid `Should not come here` case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For method overloading you can use

1. `DummyImplicit` (see **@MarioGalic**'s answer)

   ```
   def fun(x: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[Int]] = ???
   def fun(x: Seq[(String, String)])(implicit ev: DummyImplicit): Future[Seq[Int]] = ???

   fun(Seq("a", "b"))
   fun(Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d")))
   ```
2. [type class](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/#type-classes-in-scala)

   ```
   trait FunTypeclass[A] {
     def fun(x: A): Future[Seq[Int]]
   }
   object FunTypeclass {
     implicit val string: FunTypeclass[Seq[String]] = x => ???
     implicit val stringTuple2: FunTypeclass[Seq[(String, String)]] = x => ???
   }
   def fun[A](x: A)(implicit ftc: FunTypeclass[A]): Future[Seq[Int]] = ftc.fun(x)

   fun(Seq("a", "b"))
   fun(Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d")))
   ```

or

3. [magnet](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern)

   ```
   import scala.language.implicitConversions

   trait FunMagnet {
     def fun(): Future[Seq[Int]]
   }
   object FunMagnet {
     implicit def fromString(x: Seq[String]): FunMagnet = () => ???
     implicit def fromStringTuple2(x: Seq[(String, String)]): FunMagnet = () => ???
   }
   def fun(x: FunMagnet): Future[Seq[Int]] = x.fun()

   fun(Seq("a", "b"))
   fun(Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d")))
   ```

[Overloading methods based on generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643225/overloading-methods-based-on-generics/)

Answer (score 3):

Try `DummyImplicit` approach instead of `TypeTag`

```
def fun(x: Seq[String]): Future[Seq[Int]] = ???
def fun(x: Seq[(String, String)])(implicit ev: DummyImplicit): Future[Seq[Int]] = ???
```

> How can I use the values in the Seq ?

Note even though `TypeTag` enables overcoming type erasure I do not think compiler inserts a cast automatically, so you would have manually call `asInstanceOf` or equivalent

```
case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => 
  val vs: Seq[String] = values.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]
  ???
```

As a side note, `TypeTag` requires dependency on `scala-reflect.jar` (which might be a disadvantage, say, if we care about package size).

Answer (score 2):

Common practice for this situation is to use [Magnet Pattern](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scala-magnet-pattern/)

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)