# Trying to extract the TypeTag of a Sequence of classes that extend a trait with different generic type parameters

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

The following code example shows the core of my question:

```scala
// This is the base trait that the classes are extending
trait Operation[T] {
  def operate(x: T): T
}

// Here are 2 case classes that exist for the sole purpose of being
// the generic type for the classes I'm making
case class CaseClass1(field1_1: String, field1_2: String, field1_3: String)
case class CaseClass2(field2_1: String, field2_2: String, field2_3: String)

// These are the 2 classes that extend my basic trait, implementing the operate
// method with some kind of logic
class FillField1 extends Operation[CaseClass1] {
  def operate(input: CaseClass1): CaseClass1 = input.copy(field1_3 = "haha")
}
class FillField2 extends Operation[CaseClass2] {
  def operate(input: CaseClass2): CaseClass2 = input.copy(field2_2 = "hoho")
}

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
// This is a function that prints out the typetag information currently available
def someFunc[T: TypeTag](x: Operation[T]): Unit = {
  println(s"TypeTag is: ${typeOf[T]}")
}

// Here I'm creating a sequence of Operations, but they can have any generic
// type parameter
val someSeq: Seq[Operation[_]] = Seq(new FillField1, new FillField2)

someSeq.map(someFunc(_))
/*
  Output:
  TypeTag is: _$1
  TypeTag is: _$1
*/

someFunc(new FillField1)
/*
  Output:
  TypeTag is: CaseClass1
*/
```

As you can see, when I call `someFunc(new fillField1)` I can properly find my typetag at runtime. But when I'm using `someSeq`, which is a Sequence that can contain multiple types of classes I can't get the typetag I need at runtime. Is this because you lose that information at runtime?

How can I get the proper typetag at runtime? So how could I get as output `TypeTag is: CustomClass1` and `TypeTag is: CustomClass2` when I'm using that `Seq[Operation[_]]`?

I'm working on an Apache Spark project where we have a structure similar to this and when I'm using that sequence I'm getting an issue that the TypeTag points to an unknown class, `_$10` (or whatever name the compiler made for my typetag), instead of the actual TypeTag which would be `CustomClass1` or `CustomClass2`...

Comment: I'd guess it's because `someSeq` doesn't preserve the types of each element. And `TypeTag` are computed during compilation, thus at compile time it's impossible to provide the type of each element of the seq.

Comment: If you really need it, you could store the `TypeTag` as an attribute of the classes `CaseClassX`.

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kurt Please see update with magnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `TypeTag` mostly does is not runtime reflection but persisting some information (a type) from compile time to runtime.

`Seq` is a homogeneous collection (i.e. all its elements have the same type). In `Seq(new FillField1, new FillField2)` both elements have type `Operation[_]`. So when `someFunc` is applied `T` is inferred to be `_` aka `_$1` (i.e. unknown argument of existential type `Operation[_]`).

So one option is to use a heterogeneous collection (`HList`). Then the elements can have different types, these types can be captured from compile time to runtime, the types can be handled at runtime

```
import shapeless.{HNil, Poly1}

object someFuncPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[T: TypeTag, O](implicit ev: O <:< Operation[T]): Case.Aux[O, Unit] =
    at(x => someFunc(x))
}

def someFunc[T: TypeTag](x: Operation[T]): Unit = println(s"Type is: ${typeOf[T]}")

(new FillField1 :: new FillField2 :: HNil).map(someFuncPoly)
//Type is: CaseClass1
//Type is: CaseClass2
```

Another option is to use runtime reflection (i.e. what `TypeTag` doesn't do)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime
val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror

def someFunc(x: Operation[_]): Unit = {
  val xSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(x.getClass)
  val operationSymbol = xSymbol.baseClasses(1)// or just typeOf[Operation[_]].typeSymbol if you know Operation statically
  val extendee = xSymbol.typeSignature/*toType*/.baseType(operationSymbol)
  println(s"Type is: ${extendee.typeArgs.head}")
}

someSeq.map(someFunc(_))
//Type is: CaseClass1
//Type is: CaseClass2
```

Another implementation is

```
def someFunc(x: Operation[_]): Unit = {
  val xSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(x.getClass)
  val operationSymbol = xSymbol.baseClasses(1).asClass
  val operationParamType = operationSymbol.typeParams(0).asType.toType
  println(s"Type is: ${operationParamType.asSeenFrom(xSymbol.toType, operationSymbol)}")
}
```

---

One more option is magnet pattern ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643225/overloading-methods-based-on-generics) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313268/type-erasure-problem-in-method-overloading) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011072/how-to-make-a-typeclass-works-with-an-heterogenous-list-in-scala) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318180/generic-function-where-the-return-type-depends-on-the-input-type-in-scala) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651201/problem-with-bringing-into-scope-scala-implicit-conversions) [6](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73846768/scala-generic-method-no-classtag-available-for-t-when-using-collection))

```scala
trait Magnet[T] {
  def someFunc: Unit
}

import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def operationToMagnet[T: TypeTag](x: Operation[T]): Magnet[T] = new Magnet[T] {
  override def someFunc: Unit = println(s"TypeTag is: ${typeOf[T]}")
}

def someFunc[T: TypeTag](x: Operation[T]): Unit = (x: Magnet[T]).someFunc

Seq[Magnet[_]](new FillField1, new FillField2).map(_.someFunc)
// TypeTag is: CaseClass1
// TypeTag is: CaseClass2
```

---

Alternatively you can move `someFunc` inside `Operation`, move `TypeTag` from the method to the class and make `Operation` an abstract class

```scala
abstract class Operation[T: TypeTag] {
  def operate(x: T): T

  def someFunc: Unit = {
    println(s"TypeTag is: ${typeOf[T]}")
  }
}
```

```scala
(new FillField1).someFunc //TypeTag is: CaseClass1
(new FillField2).someFunc //TypeTag is: CaseClass2

someSeq.map(_.someFunc)
//TypeTag is: CaseClass1
//TypeTag is: CaseClass2
```