# Scala generic method - No ClassTag available for T - when using Collection

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, scala-reflect

I want to leverage Scala reflection to implicitly pass a ClassTag.

There are plenty solutions on StackOverflow on how to accomplish this.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

// animal input
trait AnimalInput {}
case class DogInput() extends AnimalInput
case class CatInput() extends AnimalInput

// animals
trait Animal[T <: AnimalInput] {
  def getInput(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Class[T] = {
    ct.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
  }
}
object Dog extends Animal[DogInput] {}
object Cat extends Animal[CatInput] {}
```

I can test that this is working well:

```
println(Dog.getInput) // Success: "DogInput"
println(Cat.getInput) // Success: "CatInput"
```

The problem is, the second I reference these objects in any collection, I run into trouble:

```
// Failure: "No ClassTag available for animal.T"
List(Dog, Cat).foreach(animal => println(animal.getInput))
```

I think I understand why this is happening but I'm not sure how to work around it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You could store the classtag. But what do you really want to achieve with all this? Sounds like XY problem.

Comment: This code compiles fine

Comment: @AdamBerry Please see updates with magnet and with abstract class

Comment: @Dima `No ClassTag available for animal.T` would be for type member rather then type parameter https://scastie.scala-lang.org/v79Y37eDRXuoauWA9b8uhQ OP's code compiled but worked not as he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I can't reproduce `No ClassTag available for animal.T`. Your code compiles and runs in Scala 2.13.9:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/lonnNg0fR1qb4Lg7ChDBqg

Maybe by failure you meant that for collection you don't receive classes `DogInput`, `CatInput`.

*Actually, I managed to reproduce `No ClassTag available for animal.T` for type member `T <: AnimalInput` rather than type parameter: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/v79Y37eDRXuoauWA9b8uhQ*

This question is very close to recent question [Trying to extract the TypeTag of a Sequence of classes that extend a trait with different generic type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830700/trying-to-extract-the-typetag-of-a-sequence-of-classes-that-extend-a-trait-with)

See the reasons there.

Either use a heterogeneous collection

```
object classPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[T <: AnimalInput : ClassTag, A](implicit
    ev: A <:< Animal[T]
  ): Case.Aux[A, Class[T]] =
    at(_ => classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
}

(Dog :: Cat :: HNil).map(classPoly).toList.foreach(println)
// class DogInput
// class CatInput
```

or use runtime reflection

```
trait Animal[T <: AnimalInput] {
  def getInput: Class[T] = {
    val classSymbol = runtimeMirror.classSymbol(this.getClass)
    val animalSymbol = typeOf[Animal[_]].typeSymbol 
    val extendeeType = classSymbol.typeSignature.baseType(animalSymbol)
    val extenderSymbol = extendeeType.typeArgs.head.typeSymbol.asClass
    runtimeMirror.runtimeClass(extenderSymbol).asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
  }
}

List(Dog, Cat).foreach(animal => println(animal.getInput))
// class DogInput
// class CatInput
```

The easiest is

```
trait Animal[T <: AnimalInput] {
  def getInput: Class[T]
}
object Dog extends Animal[DogInput] {
  val getInput = classOf[DogInput]
}
object Cat extends Animal[CatInput] {
  val getInput = classOf[CatInput]
}
```

---

One more option is magnet pattern ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643225/overloading-methods-based-on-generics) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313268/type-erasure-problem-in-method-overloading) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011072/how-to-make-a-typeclass-works-with-an-heterogenous-list-in-scala) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318180/generic-function-where-the-return-type-depends-on-the-input-type-in-scala) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64651201/problem-with-bringing-into-scope-scala-implicit-conversions) [6](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern))

```scala
trait AnimalMagnet[T <: AnimalInput] {
  def getInput: Class[T]
}

import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def animalToMagnet[A, T <: AnimalInput : ClassTag](a: A)(implicit
  ev: A <:< Animal[T]
): AnimalMagnet[T] = new AnimalMagnet[T] {
  override def getInput: Class[T] = classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}

List[AnimalMagnet[_]](Dog, Cat).foreach(animal => println(animal.getInput))
//class DogInput
//class CatInput
```

---

Also you can move `ClassTag` implicit from the method to the trait (and make the trait an abstract class)

```scala
abstract class Animal[T <: AnimalInput](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) {
  def getInput: Class[T] = ct.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}

List(Dog, Cat).foreach(animal => println(animal.getInput))
// class DogInput
// class CatInput
```