# Generic function where the return type depends on the input type in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying make this code to compile:

```
import cats.effect.IO

sealed trait Shape {
  val x: Int
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape

def modifyShape[S <: Shape](shape: S): IO[S] = shape match {
  case s: Square => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
  case c: Cube => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
}
```

When I'm trying to compile this code I'm getting error:

> type mismatch;
> found   : Square
> required: S
> case s: Square => IO(s.copy(y = 5))

How to make this code work?

Update:
After reading comments and articles I tried to use F-bound like this:

```
sealed trait Shape[A <: Shape[A]] { this: A =>
  val x: Int
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape[Square]
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape[Cube]

def modifyShape[S <: Shape[S]](shape: S): IO[S] = shape match {
  case s: Square => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
  case c: Cube => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
}
```

But seems I missed something. This still doesn't work.

Comment: Why is the monomorphic signature `def modifyShape(shape: Shape): IO[Shape]` not enough?

Comment: https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

Comment: @DmytroMitin Because I need real subtype to use it in other function

Comment: Ok. Thanks you. Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now `modifyShape`'s body

```
shape match {
  case s: Square => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
  case c: Cube => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
}
```

just doesn't satisfy its signature

```
def modifyShape[S <: Shape](shape: S): IO[S]
```

See details here:

[Why can't I return a concrete subtype of A if a generic subtype of A is declared as return parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668592/why-cant-i-return-a-concrete-subtype-of-a-if-a-generic-subtype-of-a-is-declared/)

[Type mismatch on abstract type used in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479695/type-mismatch-on-abstract-type-used-in-pattern-matching)

`foo[S <: Shape]` means that `foo` has to work for **any** `S` that is a subtype of `Shape`. Suppose I take `S := Shape with SomeTrait`, you don't return `IO[Shape with SomeTrait]`.

Try GADT with F-bounded type parameter

```
sealed trait Shape[S <: Shape[S]] { this: S =>
  val x: Int
  def modifyShape: IO[S]
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape[Square] {
  override def modifyShape: IO[Square] = IO(this.copy(y = 5))
}
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape[Cube] {
  override def modifyShape: IO[Cube] = IO(this.copy(z = 5))
}

def modifyShape[S <: Shape[S]](shape: S): IO[S] = shape.modifyShape
```

https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html (**@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez** reminded the link)

or GADT with F-bounded type member

```
sealed trait Shape { self =>
  val x: Int
  type S >: self.type <: Shape { type S = self.S }
  def modifyShape: IO[S]
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape {
  override type S = Square
  override def modifyShape: IO[Square] = IO(this.copy(y = 5))
}
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape {
  override type S = Cube
  override def modifyShape: IO[Cube] = IO(this.copy(z = 5))
}

def modifyShape[_S <: Shape { type S = _S}](shape: _S): IO[_S] = shape.modifyShape
// or  
// def modifyShape(shape: Shape): IO[shape.S] = shape.modifyShape
```

or GADT (without F-bound)

<sub>(see details in **@MatthiasBerndt**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64326190/5249621) and my comments to it, this code portion is from his answer)</sub>

> ```
> sealed trait Shape[A] {
>   val x: Int
> }
>
> case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape[Square]
> case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape[Cube]
>
> def modifyShape[S](shape: Shape[S]): IO[S] = shape match {
>   case s: Square => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
>   case c: Cube   => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
> }
> ```

or ADT + reflection

```
sealed trait Shape {
  val x: Int
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def modifyShape[S <: Shape : TypeTag](shape: S): IO[S] = (shape match {
  case s: Square if typeOf[S] <:< typeOf[Square] => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
  case c: Cube   if typeOf[S] <:< typeOf[Cube]   => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
}).asInstanceOf[IO[S]]
```

or ADT + type class

```
sealed trait Shape {
  val x: Int
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape

trait ModifyShape[S <: Shape] {
  def modifyShape(s: S): IO[S]
}
object ModifyShape {
  implicit val squareModifyShape: ModifyShape[Square] = s => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
  implicit val cubeModifyShape:   ModifyShape[Cube]   = c => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
}

def modifyShape[S <: Shape](shape: S)(implicit ms: ModifyShape[S]): IO[S] =
  ms.modifyShape(shape)
```

or ADT + magnet

```
sealed trait Shape {
  val x: Int
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape

import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait ModifyShape {
  type Out
  def modifyShape(): Out
}
object ModifyShape {
  implicit def fromSquare(s: Square): ModifyShape { type Out = IO[Square] } = new ModifyShape {
    override type Out = IO[Square]
    override def modifyShape(): IO[Square] = IO(s.copy(y = 5))
  }
  implicit def fromCube(c: Cube): ModifyShape { type Out = IO[Cube] } = new ModifyShape {
    override type Out = IO[Cube]
    override def modifyShape(): IO[Cube] = IO(c.copy(z = 5))
  }
}

def modifyShape(shape: ModifyShape): shape.Out = shape.modifyShape()
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to use a GADT, a generalized algebraic datatype.

In a normal (non-generalized) ADT, the case classes will take exactly the same type parameters as the sealed trait and pass them through unmodified like in this example:

```scala
sealed trait Either[A, B]
case class Left[A, B](a: A) extends Either[A, B]
case class Right[A, B](b: B) extends Either[A, B]
// both Left and Right take two type parameters, A and B,
// and simply pass them through to sealed trait Either.
```

In a generalized ADT, there is no such restriction. Therefore, `Square` and `Cube` are allowed to take a different set of type parameters than `Shape` (in this case the empty set, meaning none at all), and they can fill in the type parameter of `Shape` with something other than their own type parameters. In this case, because they don't have any type parameters that they could pass through to `Shape`, they just pass their own type.

```scala
sealed trait Shape[A] {
  val x: Int
}

case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape[Square]
case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape[Cube]
```

With this declaration, the following definition will compile:

```
  def modifyShape[S](shape: Shape[S]): IO[S] = shape match {
    case s: Square => IO(s.copy(y = 5))
    case c: Cube => IO(c.copy(z = 5))
  }
```

When the Scala compiler sees that `shape` is in fact a `Square`, it is smart enough to figure out that `S` must be `Square`, because that is what the `Square` case class passed as a type parameter to `Shape`.

But it is by no means necessary that `Square` and `Cube` pass their own type to `Shape` as a type parameter. For instance, they could pass the other one like in this example:

```scala
  sealed trait Shape[A] {
    val x: Int
  }

  case class Square(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape[Cube]
  case class Cube(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Shape[Square]

  def changeDimension[S](shape: Shape[S]): IO[S] = shape match {
    case s: Square => IO(Cube(s.x, s.y, 42))
    case c: Cube => IO(Square(c.x, c.y))
  }


  val x: IO[Square] = changeDimension(Cube(3, 6, 25))
```

Comment: Possibility of `changeDimension` can be considered as an advantage of GADT approach (over F-bound approach for example) if a user is interested in such kind of flexibility/modification or as a disadvantage if a user is interested in rigidity (returning "current" type, making `changeDimension` impossible).

Comment: By the way, if we add F-bound to the trait `Shape` and method `modifyShape` (in order to exclude situation with `Square extends Shape[Cube]` and `changeDimension`) then GADT code stops to compile.